# Deprecation of OrganizationalUnit in Subject of TLS Certificates

Tags: linux, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, self-signed-certificate

Recently we got a mail from our certificate provider that they are removing the OU field from Subject of new/renewed certificates after 1st September.
This is related to decision made by Certificate Authority Forum (https://cabforum.org/2021/06/30/ballot-sc47v2-sunset-subjectorganizationalunitname/)

My understanding is that for new certificates the CSR will not include OU field or will be ignored if given and generated certificates will not contain OU.

Will this only impact certificates from certificate authorities or will also impact self signed certificates(i.e. openssl will also remove OU attribute)?

Answer (score 1):

This affects only commercial CAs that are part of CA/Browser forum. Any privately operated CAs are not affected.